# REPLACE function of SQLite does not work on objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, replace

I am working on SQLite but when I replace the data it adds again and again to my database, basically I want to store the `alarm name`, `alarm type` and `alarm tune path`, there is should be only `6 rows` in `NotiType` because I am inserting exactly the 6 elements in every column. But the problem here is when I am replacing the data when there is change in alarm names types and tunes everyday, but the data is being inserted in every column below the and counting when ever the table is calling replace data function.

```
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath] == YES) {
    const char *dbPathagain = [_dbPath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {
        NSLog(@"database is open");
        char *errorMessage;

        const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NotiType(Alarm TEXT, Type TEXT, TPath TEXT)";


        NSLog(@"created table success");
        // sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
        //  const char *dbPathagain = [ _dbPath UTF8String];

        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath] == YES) {
            sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
            const char *dbPathagain = [_dbPath UTF8String];
            if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {
                for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < [azanst count];itemIndex++){

                    NSString *myname = [azanst objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
                    NSString *mytype = [alarmsstype objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
                    NSString *mytunepath = [alarmtune objectAtIndex:itemIndex];

                    NSString *insertSQLData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"REPLACE INTO NotiType(Alarm, Type, TPath) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")", myname, mytype, mytunepath];
                    NSLog(@"here is alarm names %@", myname);
                    NSLog(@"here alarm types %@", mytype);
                    NSLog(@"here alarm tune path %@", mytunepath);
                    const char *insert_statement = [insertSQLData UTF8String];

                    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

                    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                        NSLog(@"data added successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"could not add timings");
                    }
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_DB);
            }
        }
        if (sqlite3_exec(_DB, sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"failed to insert in table");
        }
        sqlite3_close(_DB);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to open db or cretate table");
        NSLog(@"Database Error Message : %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am doing something like this

```
     for (i=0, i<= ID.count, i++) {

                    NSString *insertSQLData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE NotiType SET Alarm =" + myname "," + "Type =" + mytype "," + "Tpath =" mytunepath + " where ID == i"];
                    }
```

Comment: if you want to access the `REPLACE` key then set any one the key as primary key

Comment: which one should be primary key ??

Comment: choice is yours, your table primary identification for e.g login page (user email is the primary key) is the primary key

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide a WHERE statement :

> NSString *insertSQLData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"REPLACE INTO
>   NotiType(Alarm, Type, TPath) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")", myname,
>   mytype, mytunepath];

you should add something like WHERE _id = %@, myAlarmUniqIdentifier to make sureyou only change the one that is beeing edited

edit : Come to think of it I also recommand using UPDATE, I'm not sure if REPLACE is what you want here..

```
UPDATE {table} SET {column1} = {editedObject.value1}, {column2} = {editedObject.value2} WHERE {uniqueIdField} = {editedObject.identifier};
```

EDIT 2 :
following your edit, update your for loop like this :

```
 NSString *myname = [azanst objectAtIndex:i];
 NSString *mytype = [alarmsstype objectAtIndex:i];
 NSString *mytunepath = [alarmtune objectAtIndex:i];
 NSNumber *myid = [ID objectAtIndex:i]; //<-- get the unique identifier for the item number ‘i‘
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE NotiType SET Alarm=%@, Type=%@, Tpath=%@ where ID=%@", myname, mytype, mytunepath, myid];
```

Comment: every data is being updated actually there is six elements in every columns and every six are being changed each day there should be no more rows than six

Comment: Replace WILL replace all the rows. So without WHERE clause, you overwrite all the field of your db with the same value. I assume this is not what you want, so you need to create a fields that will contain a unique identifer (autoincrement works wonder) and update each row WHERE identifier == rowToBeEdited.identifier

Comment: sounds well but should I make ID auto increment??

Comment: I edited my answer, I think you should consider using UPDATE rather than update. And yeah, your id field should be autoincrement, unless you want to add some logic to deal with it yourself, just add a column with attribute INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT in your create statement

Comment: but the last query seems to be ambiguous to me

Comment: What do you mean by that? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

Comment: fine now by link I have updated the question with the UPDATE code at the end of question Kindly view and analyse plz